# ManagedObject custom class init error

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have my custom Managed Object class:

```
@interface NDAEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;

+(id) entityWithText:(NSString *)text;
-(void) setText:(NSString *)text;
- (void)setPrimitiveName:(NSString *)text;

@end

@implementation NDAEntity

@dynamic text;

+(id) entityWithText:(NSString *)text{
    return [[NDAEntity alloc] initWithText:text];
}

-(id) initWithText:(NSString *)text{
    if(self = [super init]){
        [self setText:text];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setText:(NSString *)text{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"text"];
    [self setPrimitiveName:text];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"text"];
}

@end
```

And when I push button execute next code:

```
NDAEntity *entity = [NDAEntity entityWithText: @"smth"];
```

I have error:

> CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on
>   NSManagedObject class 'NDAEntity'

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just `alloc init` a managed object subclass. You *must* create the managed object instance from the entity and with reference to a context.

Generally you should be using `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` to do this.

Comment: I just have changed code like you sad: NDAEntity * entity=[[NDAEntity alloc]init]; entity.text = @"smth"; So I still have the error. PS I use Magic Record wrapper for Core Data. According some issues I do not whont to add this Managed Object entity to Managed Object Context.

Comment: I said you **can not** alloc and init a managed object subclass. You need to create from the entity description. You shouldn't be using a managed object subclass for whatever you're doing if you don't want to save it to the store...